# Some components of an adobe interactive pdf aren't showing as expected

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, adobe

I was given an interactive pdf file, it has a slide with a small slideshow (3 slides) when looked at that particular slide. There is a play button and stop button at the bottom that appears/disappears if you move your mouse over it, and we can choose to play it or stop it. I don't know if its a video though. But, there is some interactivity in that slide. I tried to embed this pdf in an HTML file iframe. It works for the most part but the interactivity doesn't work in chrome: I have Version 53.0.2785.143 m of chrome.
However, not sure if by fluke or what, in IE 11 its working. Any ideas on how this can be made to work on chrome?  I am using a simple iframe

```
<iframe src="file://C:\Users\svboll\embed-pdf\Interactive.pdf"
style="width:718px; height:700px;"
frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE 11 uses the Adobe Reader plugin (if available and it sounds like it is) to display the PDF in the iFrame so you'll see the interactivity play correctly there. Edge doesn't and neither does Chrome. Chrome uses it's own built-in PDF viewer which doesn't support most interactivity. For interactive PDF, you simply *will not* be able to create a consistent experience of PDF in an iframe across browsers, platforms, and devices. This is not a limitation of PDF, it's a limitation of the viewers in that they have not fully implemented the PDF specification.